# iOS VPP or Entreprise program for software house

Tags: ios

I've a problem to understand apple developer program enrollment for businness: I work in a software house, we have to develop an iOS app for an company A: probably (in future), we'll need to develop another app for a company B, but we want that A company can't get B app and viceversa.

I've googled a lot and I got that company A and company B must both subscribe to Enterprise program (I think...).

My questions are:

1) is correct what I've understand about Enterprise program?

2) is possible to make it whit VPP, remembering that A company can't see, download, use, etc... B app and viceversa?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow!

I think that your question is more about SDLC organization and law than about programming itself. So here https://law.stackexchange.com/ it looks like more suitable place for such questions

Answer (score 0):

Enterprise distribution is only for "in-house" targets.

For example: My company has a very specific, custom "time-card" system, so I develop an app to use that system and distribute it to my employees.

VPP - Volume Purchasing Program - is for 3rd-party developer to create and sell a customized app for a client.

For example: I know of a company that has a very specific, custom "time-card" system, so I develop an app to use that system. I then sell it as B2B (Business to Business) for that company to purchase in volume / bulk for their employees to use.

**Edit:** From the Apple guide https://images.apple.com/business/docs/VPP_Business_Guide.pdf ...

> Custom B2B apps built for you by a third-party developer are made available only to you. No other VPP   participant can see or get your custom apps, making the transaction both secure and private.

Comment: Ok, but with VPP can I make two distinct "repositories" for company, so that a company does not see the apps of the others companies?

Comment: Correct - see my edited answer.